# Checkbox in user edit page

Tags: users, entities

I have customized the user-edit page in Drupal7 using `user-profile-edit.tpl.php`.  I have also added reCAPTCHA to it using the [reCAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module.

I would also like it so that there is an *"I agree to terms and conditions"* checkbox, and only when the user clicks this check box should the information be saved (i.e, it should be a required field).

How can I do that?

I found the [Terms of Use](http://drupal.org/project/terms_of_use) module and the [Legal](http://drupal.org/project/legal) module but they appear only on the registration form, whereas I want it in user-edit page (form). I thought of adding a field to the account settings for users but I am not getting any desired field for that.

Any suggestions?

Following the answer below, I was able to do some progress. However I want it to be a required field and if I click on that in its field setting then automatically it is shown on the user registration page which I do not want [image: As you can see in the image if required field is selected then automatically it is displayed on registration form which I do not want...I only want it to appear in the user-edit page].

Comment: Any Ideas or suggestions please...is it that hard to achieve?

Comment: Any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You can select the Boolean field and widget type as Single on/off check box...This should solve your problem...No need to use any modules

Comment: yes but i want it to be a required field and if i click on that in its field setting then automatically it is shown on the user registration page which i do not want

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module in combination with the checkbox you've already set up if I'm reading your requirements correctly.

1) Set up your Boolean field as you already have

2) Set the field permissions so that only registered users can see/edit it

This will mean that when a user registers, they will not be able to see or edit the field, but as soon as they have registered they get the permissions on the field and it will become viewable on the user edit page.

Comment: i did that but its still appearing on the user registration page

Comment: hmm...if you make it an unrequired field (just for now), does it still show on the user registration page?  One option would be to make it unrequired, and then use Rules to ensure it is filled in on the user edit page.

Comment: if its not a required field then its not appearing...the rules idea sounds interesting...let me work on it...will keep you posted...thanks

Comment: btw what condition should i have in the rule...i have figure out the action and event but stuck at condition

Comment: ok so in condition i added check data value to be empty and negated it

Comment: From the top of my head, I think it'll be *entity has field* or *field has value* or something.  It'll probably end up looking something like *Entity has field* `account:field_mycheckbox` **AND** *Field has value* `account:field_mycheckbox = 0`* (or 1 depending on your Rule Action).

Comment: yes i am trying to do that but when i enter a 0 or a 1 i get an error:  Data selector 1 for parameter value is invalid.

Comment: It's *possible* that it's looking for a value rather than a key.  In fact, that makes more sense as you're checking if `field has value`. Try checking for the on/off values you set in the field settings.

Comment: i have set the ON value as 1 and OFF value as 0 (the defaults are also the same)

Comment: and also i have set the default as 1 only

Comment: any ideas/suggestions